# Can a MacBook Air support 2560x1600 output via HDMI using a Mini DisplayPort/Thunderbolt to HMDI adaptor?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, displayport, hdmi

The [HDMI 1.3 spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.3) can carry signals with resolutions as high as 2560 x 1600 pixels. Is it possible to output this high a resolution signal from a MacBook Air using a Mini DisplayPort/Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter? If so, are there any special considerations for buying this adapter or will any adapter on the market work?

Machine is 2012 MacBook Air

Comment: Shopping questions are generally off topic on AD. But this question could be re-stated to be relevant without being a shopping question. I've made some edits, but please keep editing if you think I've mis-characterized the question you had intended to ask.

Comment: Please include the model of MacBook Air you're using in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was unable to get anything higher than 1080p with HDMI with several different adapters and monitors. Dual link DVI works with an active mini display port to dual link DVI adapter at 2560x1440 with my MacBook Air 2012.

Given that I haven't gotten my Windows box HDMI or other laptop HDMI to go at 2560x1440 either I would have to answer 'NO' to the question for MacBook Air 2012 and earlier. MacBook Air 2013 or newer seems to work fine.

Answer (score 11):

I own a 2013 MacBook Air.  This is equipped with a Thunderbolt 1 port :

`Mini-DisplayPort -> HDMI` adapter (1920x1200 max.)

`Mini-DisplayPort -> DisplayPort` adapter (upto 2560x1600 max.)

I've used both and am now driving daily on my MBA 13" with a monitor running at 2560x1440.

Comment: That's what I've found as well, thanks for sharing

Comment: How's the performance? Do you experience any hiccups caused by driving such a high-res display on an older Mac? I'd like to get a 2560x1440 display for my Macbook Air 2015 and I'm wondering if the resolution would be an issue.

Comment: @macbem I have a mid-2013 so just keep this in mind, and I used it mainly for 2D applications or youtube at most... everything was very nice to me.. couldn't see any shearing

Comment: I guess everything will be fine as well for me, as I usually just browse the web and code.

Comment: I now code on a MBP .. the graphics are better but I didn't notice anything wrong.. just got spoiled after that retina display and 4K .. I think you would be fine

Answer (score 2):

I have a 2013 Macbook Air connected to Dell monitor (2560 x 1440) which does not have DisplayPort, so I have to use a mini Displayport to HDMI adapter.

Under MacOS, as everyone else has said, it can only do 2048x1080:
[image]

However, when I Boot Camp into Windows 10, it supports the native resolution of the monitor:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've used [this adapter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=5311&seq=1&format=2) for years with various different MacBook Pros, TVs, projectors, and monitors without any problem.  The resolution that you can output is likely only limited by your video card and monitor, probably not the cable.

[HDMI 1.3 supports 2560x1600](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdmi#Version_comparison).  What monitor are you connecting the MBA to?

Which model year is your MacBook Air?

Comment: 2012 MacBook Air, monitor is this one http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=110999782383&ssPageName=ADME:L:OC:US:3160

Comment: The MacBook Air 2012 can output to a Thunderbolt Display at 2560x1440 (the same resolution as the display you are looking at). You should be good.

Comment: John, the product you linked to claims "*The adapter supports resolutions up to 1920x1080p*". The original question asks about 2560x1600. Quite often the capabilities of the cable *does* matter.